# Moving text, side by side after n number of lines

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to move text side-by-side after a gap in the text.

My example is

```
684 0.00000 
685 0.00000 
686 0.99490 

684 0.00000 
685 0.00000 
686 0.76000
```

I would like the text to be as follows

```
684 0.00000 684 0.00000 
685 0.00000 685 0.00000 
686 0.99490 686 0.76000
```

I have tried but this hasn't produced the desired output.

```
awk 'NR%1{printf "%s ",$0;next;}'1 file.txt
```

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: If input has 3rd instance of `684 0.00000` then where will it go in output?

Comment: @anubhava are you sure original poster did not intentionally leave the empty line between the blocks ? The edit last made removed this. That way it's a different solution.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was fixing editing issue. Rolled back my changes.

Comment: Hello, my mistake, I have removed the "\" they were there in error and are not intended in the output.

Comment: I still didn't get answer of my question I asked yesterday in first comment

Comment: @anubhava Sorry for not clarifying this further. For context I am looking at secondary structure of a protein. The first column indicates the residue number and second indicates the % average secondary structure. Therefore 684 0.0000 three times, just means there is no secondary structure e.g. alpha-helix, beta-strand three times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
(NR == 1) || !NF {
    numCols++
    numRows = 0
}
NF {
    vals[++numRows,numCols] = $0
}
END {
    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
684 0.00000 684 0.00000
685 0.00000 685 0.00000
686 0.99490 686 0.76000
```

Comment: Thus far, the only solution that matches the requested output. I would expect no less `:)`

Comment: Hello @Ed Morton I am not sure how to execute your solution. As I have indicated the backslashes are a mistake in my original post, sorry about this. My file is called line_seperared.agr, how could this be added to your solution? Dan.

Comment: Change `awk -f tst.awk file` to `awk -f tst.awk line_seperared.agr`. I updated it to not have to deal with those backslashes.

Comment: Note: this solution works for multiple blocks of "N" lines.

Comment: Hello @EdMorton I have tried to implement your solution, however I get the syntax error awk: tsk.awk:1: cat tst.awk awk: tsk.awk:1:        ^ syntax error

Comment: @Dan then you did something wrong when copy/pasting it. The script WILL work exactly as shown using any awk. Oh,hang on - from  that error message it looks like you must have included `$ cat tst.awk` inside `tst.awk`. Don't do that - that's the command to show the file contents, it's not part of the file, the file should only contain the awk script, the part starting from `(NR == 1) || !NF {`

Answer (score 4):

```
$ pr -2t file
```

there will be an empty line at the end, which can be trimmed by piping to `... | sed '$d'`

Comment: Perhaps `pr -2t <(sed 's/[ \\]*$//' file)` if those trailing spaces and `\` are a true condition...

Comment: Perhaps, not sure what those are for.

Comment: What about the `'\\'` left between the columns or removed entirely with the process substitution shown by @dawg?

Comment: Hello @karakfa how could I try this solution with 29 lines of text?

Comment: if you have 14 + blank + 14 lines, this should fold into a block of 15 where the last line is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `awk` that should work with any version of `awk`:

```bash
awk '
!NF {
   n = 0
   next
}
{
   rec[n] = (++n in rec ? rec[n] OFS : "") $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print rec[i]
}' file

684 0.00000  684 0.00000
685 0.00000  685 0.00000
686 0.99490  686 0.76000
```

Comment: Hello @anubhava Thank you for your solution. I notice that there should a ";" n = 0;next. Otherwise I get a syntax error. Could this solution work for n=29 lines. Dan

Comment: If those 2 statements are without line break then you will need a ; otherwise not required as I have shown. Yes it will work for any number of n value so 29 would be fine

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. I figure out why the main source file didn't work as there was a space at the top of the text, but all is well now. Thanks once again. Dan.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set a column when seeing the empty line, using [multidimensional arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html). Something like this:

This is the AWK script, a plain text file. Call it "`2col.awk`".

```
BEGIN{
 # -- initialize variables. Recommended.
   column=0
   i=1
}

{
if ($0=="") {    # if line is empty
    column=1     # switch column
    i=1          # reset again
    next         # and move on
  }
  arr[column, i]=$0
  i+=1
}

# -- at the end of file parsing: print it out.
END{
    for (myindex = 1; myindex < i; ++myindex) {
        print arr[0,myindex] "  "  arr[1,myindex]
    }
}
```

Call the script from command line like this:

`awk -f 2col.awk  myfilename.ext`

where `myfilename.ext` is the file containing source data.

Given data:

```
a
b
c

d
e
f
```

result will be

```
a b
c d
e f
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. You are correct to say that the backslashes are not intended, but I am unsure execute your solution, the file name is line_seperated.agr but how would i execute this from the terminal?

Comment: @Dan as you can see in other solutions above, replace the sample filename `myfilename.ext` with the actual name your file has. So something along `awk -f 2col.awk  line_seperated.agr`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This works on my example with three lines, but my actual data has 29 lines then separated by a gap. Could this awk command be amended to work this many lines of n separated by a gap. Dan

Comment: The script by Ed Morton will work on any number of lines, on any number of repeat blocks. So you could have a pattern of 37 lines, 1 blank, and repeat that 9 times. It would still work. My script assumes only two blocks, but works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '! (___+=NR * !NF) ? (__[NR] = $_)*(NF = _) : __[NR-___]==$_ \
          ? $+NF =$_ : ($!NF = __[NR-___] RS $_)^_^sub("[ \t]*[\\\\]?\n"," ")'

684 0.00000 684 0.00000 \
685 0.00000 685 0.00000 \
686 0.99490 686 0.76000
```

another approach via `FS/OFS` :

```
mawk '(____+=NR*!NF) ? (__ = $_) ($_=___[NR-____])($++NF=__)^(__=_) \  
                     : (___[NR] = $_) * (NF = _)'     FS='[\\\\]$' OFS=
```

Comment: And we have another correct answer, but for readability, though purely a personal taste type thing, I think this lacks slightly compared to the other correct answer on the page -- though still worth the vote for pure correctness.

Comment: I appreciate the answer using fewest characters. Cryptic onlineliners :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : and also the only `awk` based solution requiring neither multi-dimensional arrays nor (nested) `for` loops

Comment: I noticed that -- which was really nice. I took at bit of head scratching, but that was good logic.

Comment: @MyICQ : what so cryptic about it ? the only things i used were add-assign `(+=)`, subtraction `(-)`, multiplication `(*)`, exponentiation `(^)`, negation `(!)`,  variable/array cell value assign, a ternary if-then-else, and string concat - that's it